# Can a Swift Universal app run UIActionSheet and/or UIActionController from one build or are these still broken?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, swift, ios8

Using Xcode6-Beta5 I've built a Universal Swift app with a Deployment Target of 7.0.
I built a test app which has both UIActionSheet and UIAlertController - a button selects which one is called at run-time.

To summarize first:
1. Putting 8.0 stuff into the app causes launch failure in 7.1 devices, even without executing the 8.0 code.  The 8.0 calls pollute the app.
2. Neither UIActionSheet nor UIAlertController work at all on iPad 8.0 devices.

Running in the Simulator:
All iPhone 8.0 targets can display both UIActionSheet and UIAlertController successfully.
All iPhone 7.1 targets fail to launch with symbol not found errors for UIAlertAction or UIAlertController.  This is a dyld_fatal_error.

All iPad 7.1 targets fail to even launch, the same way the iPhone 7.1 targets fail.
If I comment out the UIActionController and UIActionAlert code then the app works on 7.1 devices running UIActionSheet.

In all iPad 8.0 targets running UIActionSheet display nothing and generates about 80 lines of NSLayoutConstraint problems.
In all iPad 8.0 targets running UIActionController throws a SIGABRT into AppDelegate with:

2014-08-15 10:21:51.799 AlertControllerTest[1828:246107] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController: 0x78651780>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

1. Are these still broken in Xcode6-Beta5 or am I doing something wrong?
2. Is it supposed to be possible to run on 7.1 apps built with 8.0 functions as long as the 8.0 functions are not invoked?  Earlier versions used to work that way.

Before someone asks to see the source code (now revised for best with GM):

```
    @IBAction func tapHereTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if sheetOrControllerButton.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        var actionSheet = UIActionSheet()
        actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Choice 1")
        actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Choice 2")
        actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Choice 3")
        actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Choice 4")
        actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
            actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Dummy")
            let systemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion
            if NSString(string: UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion).doubleValue >= 8 {
                //actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 4
                //actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 5
            } else {
                actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 4
            }
        } else {
            actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 4
        }
        actionSheet.title = "Pick a Number"
        actionSheet.delegate = self
        actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
    } else {
        var actionSheet:UIAlertController

        if sheetOrControllerButton.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Pick a Number", message: "Why?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        } else {
            actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Pick a Number", message: "Why?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
            if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
                var button = sender as UIButton
                actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = button.bounds
                actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button.viewForBaselineLayout()
            }
        }
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choice 1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action :UIAlertAction!)in
            println("Picked 1")
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choice 2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action :UIAlertAction!)in
            println("Picked 2")
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choice 3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action :UIAlertAction!)in
            println("Picked 3")
        }))
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
            actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action :UIAlertAction!)in
                println("Canceled")
            }))
        } else {
            actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action :UIAlertAction!)in
                println("Canceled")
            }))
        }
        self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func actionSheet(theActionSheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        println("Picked 1")
    } else if buttonIndex == 1 {
        println("Picked 2")
    } else if buttonIndex == 2 {
        println("Picked 3")
    } else if buttonIndex == 3 {
        println("Picked 4")
    } else if buttonIndex == 4 {
        println("Canceled")
    } else {
        println("What??")
    }
}
```

I get the same behavior on physical iPhone 4 - 7.1, iPad 2 - 7.1  All 8.0 testing was in Simulator - I haven't put 8.0 on any device yet not wanting to brick it.

Thanks all.

UPDATED for Beta6:
Note - this is still Simulator testing.
We now have complete work-arounds to build a Universal app that will work on 7.1 and 8.0.
iPhone - Test for iOS version and use UIActionSheet or UIAlertController as needed.  Both .ActionSheet and .Alert styles work on 8.0.

iPad 7.1 - UIActionSheet now "works", but you need to add a dummy extra button - it fails to display the last button added.
iPad 8.0 - UIAlertController .Alert works, but looks bad, and .ActionSheet still crashes as does UIActionSheet.

UPDATED for Beta7:
No changes.  iPhones work as expected.  iPads still broken as above.

UPDATED for GM:
Some improvement for iPad 8.0.  (Or else I didn't figure it out before.)
iPhones still work correctly.  Including the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus in the simulator.

iPad 7.1 - UIActionSheet still needs dummy button.  The cancelButtonIndex will darken the text to indicate that it's the cancel button, but it does not offset it.

iPad 8.0 - UIActionSheet doesn't crash, but don't use it. If the cancelButtonIndex is not -1 then there are problems with which buttons at the end of the list are displayed.  It might still need a dummy button.  But now the cancelButtonIndex must be set to the dummy button (which will not display).  But even worse, the clickedButtonAtIndex is called twice, once with the clicked button and once with the cancelButtonIndex.  It's as though it's detecting a bogus  when the action sheet closes.

iPad 8.0 - UIAlertController with .Alert is still OK.
iPad 8.0 - UIAlertController with .ActionSheet can now work if the popoverPresentationController sourceRect and sourceView are set.  (This was possibly the case earlier, too, but I'm not going to retest the older betas.).  But, there's one more gotcha -- UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel causes the button to disappear, so don't use it.

UPDATED for 6.0.1:
iPad 7.1 - UIActionSheet still needs dummy button.
iPad 8.0 - UIAlertController with .Alert is OK.  The button with UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel is automatically placed at the bottom of the list of buttons.
iPad 8.0 - UIAlertController with .ActionSheet still needs the popoverPresentationController values set.  And UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel still fails.

Summary - no improvements yet:
iPhone - all versions work fine - can use UIActionSheet and UIAlertController as .Alert and .ActionSheet.
iPad 7.1 - UIActionSheet works with dummy.
iPad 8.0 - UIAlertController works as .Alert and .ActionSheet.  Don't use UIActionSheet.

Comment: With Xcode6-Beta6 the iPhone 7.x versions now run correctly.  They will launch even when they contain the iOS 8 code.  Executing the iOS 7 code works, running the iOS 8 code will crash, but that can be avoided by testing for iOS version, etc.  The iPad versions still don't work on either the iOS 7 or iOS 8 code, but they will launch.

Comment: Even the latest version of the UICatalog sample code (updated 2014-08-15) still crashes when creating a UIAlertController(..., preferredStyle: .ActionSheet) on iPad Simulators.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior with Objective C code on iPad targets in Xcode 6. I reported it awhile ago to Apple.

Comment: It looks like the GM of iOS 8 fixed the UIActionSheet problems. We're seeing it working in our app.

Comment: Are you able to get the UIActionSheet (which we shouldn't be using for iOS 8 anyway) to work on the iPad 8.0 in Xcode 6 GM?  I encountered flaky behavior when setting the cancelButtonIndex.  (See above.)  My app now contains several places where I switch between UIAlertView and UIAlertController at runtime based upon iOS version.  Eventually I'll create a wrapper class to hide all that, but it's faster to cut-and-paste right now.

Comment: Yeah, prior to the GM i wrote a wrapper class that handled it all transparently, and saw all the behavior you described above. But once the GM came out, it appears that apple fixed their constraints on UIActionSheet. My app was built with xcode 5, on ios8 gm. I am not 100% sure about Xcode 6 on iOS 8 with UIActionSheet.

Comment: I'm using the Xcode 6 GM, not the iOS 8 GM, so there's probably a difference there.  There's still other bugs in the GM - for instance Game Center player authorization never returns a success code so you have to "assume" that it's ok to go on.  If some of the other bugs were gone in the iOS 8 GM that would imply that the fixes will eventually migrate into Xcode 6 as well.